# Ruby: what method is called?

Tags: ruby, object, methods, overriding

Assume, I have an object `x` of `MyClass`. What method is called, when I do `puts x`? I need to override it with my own one.

I thought it was `.inspect`, but somehow overridden `inspect` isn't being called.

For example, I have a class `Sum`:

```
class Sum
  initiazlie a, b
     @x = a + b
  end
end
```

And I wanna access the result like this:

```
s = Sum.new(3,4)
puts s         #=>    7   How do I do this?
puts 10 + s    #=>   17   or even this...?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls: `to_s`

```
class Sum
  def to_s
    "foobar"
  end
end

puts Sum.new #=> 'foobar'
```

Or if you want, you can just call `inspect` from `to_s`, so that you have a consistent string representation of your object.

```
class Sum
  def to_s
    inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your Sum class is invalid. The definition should be.

```
class Sum
  def initialize(a, b)
     @x = a + b
  end
end
```

By default, the method called to get a human readable representation is inspect. Try this in `irb`

```
$ s = Sum.new(3, 4)
# => #<Sum:0x10041e7a8 @x=7>
$ s.inspect
# => "#<Sum:0x10041e7a8 @x=7>"
```

But in your case, you use the `puts` method which forces a string conversion. For this reason, the `Sum` object is first converted to string using the `to_s` method.

```
$ s = Sum.new(3, 4)
# => #<Sum:0x10041e7a8 @x=7>
$ puts s
# => #<Sum:0x10041e7a8>
$ puts s.to_s
# => #<Sum:0x10041e7a8>
```

Also note your last example fall into a third case. Because you sum a Fixnum + an other object, the result is expected to be a Fixnum and the method called is `to_s` but the one defined in the Fixnum class.

In order to use the one in your Sum class, you need to switch the items in the sum and define the `+` in your object.

```
class Sum
  def initialize(a, b)
     @x = a + b
  end
  def +(other)
     @x + other
  end
  def to_s
    @x.to_s
  end
end

s = Sum.new(3, 4)
s + 10
puts s
# => 17
```